# Integral calculus answer steps

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, definite-integrals

How do i get from point 1 to 2 in the answer provided and then to point 3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3852.jpg

> Define $$P = \frac{x^3-4x-3}{x^2+1}$$
>
> $$\text{ Use the rule } \int{f(x) \pm g(x) dx} = \int f(x) \space dx \pm \int \space g(x) \space dx$$
>
> And use substuitun $r = {x^2 +1}$ to evaluate $\int P dx$.
>
> ### Answer :
>
> $$ r = x^2+1 \implies dr = 2xdx \text{ and } x^2 = r-1$$
>   $$ (1 .)\space \space \space P \space dx = \int \frac{x^3 }{x^2+1} dx - \int \frac{4x }{x^2+1}dx - \int\frac{3 }{x^2+1}dx$$
>
> $$(2.)\space \space \space \frac12 \int \frac {x^2}{x^2+1}2xdx - 2 \int \frac{1}{x^2+1} 2xdx - 3 \int \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$$
>
> $$(3.)\space \space \space \frac12 \int \frac{r-1}{r}dr -2 \int \frac{1}{r}dr  - 3\int \frac{1}{x^2+1} dx$$
>
> $$  = \frac12(r-\ln |r|) - 2 \in |r| - 3 \tan ^{-1}x +C$$
>
> $$ = \frac12 (x^2+1) - \frac 52 (\ln {|x^2+1|})- 3 \tan ^{-1}x +C$$

Comment: By taking the constants out of intergral

Comment: and then substituting $r=x^2+1$

Answer (score 1):

You can take the constant out: $\int af(x)dx = a \int f(x)dx$, so for example:

$$\int \frac{x^3}{x^2 + 1}dx=\int \frac{\frac{1}{2}x^2 \times2x}{x^2 + 1}dx = \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{x^2}{x^2 + 1}2xdx$$

It's because integral is [linear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral#Linearity).

Then you can substitute $r=x^2+1$

Comment: Thanks, what about the 2nd part 4x . How would i take out the constant

Answer (score 1):

For $$\int \frac {x^3}{(x^2+1)} dx \space \space \space \space  \text{ (A.)}$$

by substituting $x^2+1=r  ∴ x^2=r-1$

you get $2x dx =dr$

So eq. $(A)$ can be written as

dividing and multiplying by 2

$$= \frac12 \int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+1)}2x dx$$

$$ = \frac12 ∫\frac {(r-1)}r.dr $$

Similarly  $4x$ can be written as $2.2x$ and $2$ is taken out of the integral.